# If $AB=I$ show that $A$ has full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $A,B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Show that if $AB=I$ then $B$ has full rank.

---

In fact, I show that $A$ has full rank, which is quite obvious but I really have difficulties to show that $B$ has full rank. I tried by contradiction : there is $u\in \mathbb R^n$ s.t. $Bv\neq u$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^n$. So $v=ABv\neq Au$ which contradict $A$ has full rank.

It doesn't look correct. What do you think ?

Comment: Why it is obvious that A has full rank? That is what is to be answered

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a dimensional argument.

Let $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ be some basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then
$$
rank(B)=dim(Span(Be_1,\dots,Be_n)),
$$
and
$$
rank(AB)=dim(Span(ABe_1,\dots,ABe_n)).
$$
This only uses the linearity of $A$ and $B$. For example if $u$ is such that $Bv=u$ for some $v$, then you can write $u=Bv=B(a_1\cdot e_1 + \dots + a_n\cdot e_n) = a_1\cdot Be_1 + \dots + a_n\cdot Be_n$, where $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are some scalars.

Now you know that $rank(AB)=n$, so $(ABe_1,\dots,ABe_n)$ are linearly independent (there is $n$ of them). That necessarily means that $(Be_1,\dots,Be_n)$ is also linearly independent, since if not, i.e., if $\sum_{i=1}^n(a_iBe_i)=0$ is some non-trivial linear combination yielding $0$, then $0=A0=A(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_iBe_i))=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_iABe_i)$, so also $(ABe_1,\dots,ABe_n)$ would be linearlt dependent. Hence, B has full rank.

$A$ must clearly have full rank, since if there is some vector $u$ not in the image of $A$, then $u$ in particular cannot be in the image of $AB$, because $B$ could only "feed" less then everything to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Because if $rank(B)<n$ so $\det B=0$ and  $$1=\det(I)=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=0,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: It seems to me that an argument with determinants will not really provide the important insight to a basic question like this.

Comment: @OnDragi Are you sure? See please better a question.

Comment: I would expect that someone trying to solve an exercise like this might not have worked with determinants yet. And I would probably even use this fact as a part of the proof that $\textrm{det}(AB)=\textrm{det}(A)\textrm{det}(B)$ rather then vice versa in class.

Comment: @OnDragi It's might, but also it's might that it's not so. But I understood your point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing thing. How do you know that $Bv\neq u\implies ABv\neq Au$? At this point, you need to use the fact that $A\text{ surjective}\implies A\text{ injective}$. Then, since $AB=\operatorname{Id}$, your argument is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you show that $A$ has full rank, then you are done. Because, 
$$AB=I\Longrightarrow B^TA^T=I$$
Hence, $B^T$ has full rank (because that is first matrix here) and hence $B$ (as row rank=column rank).

**Your argument is correct**

Because injectivity of $A$ is implied by its surjectivity.
($A$ is surjective as $$\forall x\in \mathbb R^n\exists Bx :A(Bx)=x$$)

**Alternative direct approach**

Suppose that $B$ doesn't have full rank. Then, 
$$\exists x\neq 0 : Bx=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow ABx=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow Ix=0$$
which is a contradicton.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score -1):

$AB = I$ means $B = A^-1$, so $A$ is invertible. A matrix is only invertible if it is full rank, otherwise when you are in the process of inverting it, you will eventually find a row or colum of zeros.

Comment: Sorry, but the exercise is to show that if a $n\times n$ matrix is invertible at right, then it's invertible at left (without rank theorem), so I can't use that $AB=I\implies B=A^{-1}$.